# Distance measurement in Image Processing

Tags: java, image, javacv, rapidminer

I am really hoping someone can help me out, because I'm really stuck on this one. I will have a large dataset of image needing processing, which due to the size of the set can not be processed by hand.

What needs to be done is I need to find a horizontal pixel distance in a set of about 30 objects per image. The objects are all the same shape and similar color (i.e. a shade lighter/darker). The X/Y 0,0 will be assigned to the center X bottom Y borders of the lowest Y object, from there I need to measure and record the x axis distance to the center of each of the remaining 29 objects in the image. The center part isn't really necessary as I can reformulate to realign to center, and the main purpose of this isn't necessarily the x/y coordinates, but a pattern they show/have.

I have been able to utilize Photoshop, as well as Rapidminer with IMMI extension to extract the objects, however I cannot find any tools that measure the distances. I have looked at JavaCV, but didn't see anything that can accomplish that. If someone has any idea of a toolkit, Java or otherwise, please let me know!

How do I measure the distance between 2 objects I've already found?

Comment: What's your question? Is the question, "How do I measure the distance between 2 objects I've already found?" Or something else?

Comment: Exactly, how to measure the distance between objects already found

Comment: @trashgod Thank You!! I actually have it downloaded just haven't played with it yet

Comment: @Andrew Thompson It was like 11PM, I was tired lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ImageJ`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/) is widely used in this context. You may be able to find an existing [plugin](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/index.html) or use the extensive [macro](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/macro/macros.html) language.

Answer (score 2):

If you have less images to measure you can use KLONK Image Measurement for Windows. Download and use the free version: http://www.imagemeasurement.com